# Delete everything after pattern including pattern

Tags: string, unix, awk, sed

I have a text file like

```
some
important
content
goes here
---from here--
some 
unwanted content
```

I am trying to delete all lines after `---from here--` including `---from here--`. That is, the desired output is

```
some
important
content
goes here
```

I tried `sed '1,/---from here--/!d' input.txt` but it's not removing the `---from here--` part. If I use `sed '/---from here--.*/d' input.txt`, it's only removing `---from here--` text.

How can I remove lines after a pattern including that pattern?

**EDIT**

I can achieve it by doing the first operation and pipe its output to second, like `sed '1,/---from here--/!d' input.txt | sed '/---from here--.*/d' > outputput.txt`.
Is there a single step solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach with sed:

```
sed '/---from here--/,$d' file
```

The `d`(delete) command is applied to all lines from first line containing `---from here--` up to the end of file(`$`)

Answer (score 2):

Another awk approach:

```
awk '/---from here--/{exit}1' file
```

If you have GNU awk 4.1.0+, you can add `-i inplace` to change the file in-place.
Otherwise appened `| tee file` to change the file in-place.

Comment: I believe **this** is the right solution. :-). This will be an order of magnitude faster than [@SLePort's sed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54521012/1745001) if the target regexp occurs early in a large file and no slower under any other condition. Try `time seq 1000000 | sed '/10/,$d' >/dev/null` vs `time seq 1000000 | awk '/10/{exit}1' >/dev/null` and notice awk is far faster, then change `10` to `999999` and repeat and notice they're about the same speed.

Comment: @EdMorton  Thanks, OP didn't include `awk` tag actually :-)

Comment: That just means they didn't think of awk when they posted the question, we should definitely show them the better way if/when we know it.

Comment: How can I do in place replacement. ie, write content to same file

Comment: Ah Thank you :) But I am on macOS :(

Comment: @Johnykutty Oh, then you can try ` | tee file` way to see if it works. And I would suggest you `brew install gawk` to use `gawk` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following(in case you are ok with `awk`).

```
awk '/--from here--/{found_from=1} !found_from{print}' Input_file
```

Comment: Never include a negative word like `no` in a variable name because then you introduce a high risk of introducing a double-negative to your script, as you've done with `!no_print` (`not no print` - i.e. `print`). Double negatives are always far more difficult to understand and so far easier to cause bugs in your code. Keep all variable names positive to greatly reduce that risk.

Comment: Also avoid using variable names that are commands (e.g. `print` or `no_print`) as that introduces control coupling where one part of your code is telling another part what to do. Instead use names that are conditions, like `found_from` and then let the later parts of your code decide what to do when that condition is true - that'll make your code more loosely coupled and so much easier to enhance later (e.g. what if 6 months from now you decide you DON'T want to print when `from here` appears but instead want to exit?)

Comment: @EdMorton, sorry Ed I forgot, I will try not to keep these common words now, have changed it now. Thank you for being with me always :) have a great day ahead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive, but I believe this will work:

```
sed -n '/---from here--/q; p' file
```

The `q` command tells `sed` to quit processing input lines after matching a given line.

Comment: giving error sed: 1: "q/---from here---/": extra characters at the end of q command

Comment: Sorry, fixed it: the `q` goes after (to the right of) the regex.

Comment: I think this is similar to `sed '1,/---from here--/!d' input.txt`

Comment: Yeah, @SLePort got the correct answer. Kindly disregard mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Perl

```
perl -ne ' $x++ if /---from here--/; print if !$x '
```

using your inputs..

```
$ cat johnykutty.txt
some
important
content
goes here
---from here--
some
unwanted content

$ perl -ne ' $x++ if /---from here--/; print if !$x ' johnykutty.txt
some
important
content
goes here

$
```